Why don't I hear overtones as a chord
I play piano for a while now and I was used to the idea that every key there produces a single note. Recently I've started reading the lectures on music theory that explain music sounds as standing waves of a certain frequency. Such waves tend to come with the accompanying harmonics or overtones (with frequencies being 2x, 3x, ... of the fundamental frequency). In particular, when one plays C they also produce C,G,C,E,... which are the components of the major triad. However, when I play the major triad itself, it has a much more distinct color/sound to me. In a sense, I perceive a single C as something "neutral" while Cmaj triad/Cmin triad having fitting but different hues to the single C, both equally legit. How can this be if first overtones of C form a major triad though?

Closely related but not quite duplicate—almost the opposite question, in a sense: "Why don't I hear a chord as a single tone with overtones?"

@AndyBonner sounds (with overtones) like an equivalent question to me tbh

Many things in nature tend to allow for stable waves at more or less multiples of a base pitch. This is a result of simple physical limitations (if I have a vibating string I can only get waveforms that have a node at the ends, and such stuff). But this means that most simple sounds produced tend to feature more or less harmonic overtones. This means that our brain is used to experience them and will correct for them.
Hereby the more consonant a sound is, the easier it will be for the brain to interpret notes as harmonics of the lower ones. You can test this out yourself. If you play on a reasonably tuned piano root + octave + 12th + 15th +  17th + 19th ... this will sound quite pure (start from below and keep adding notes).
But if you play a simple C major triad — C-E-G — then clearly neither E nor G are harmonics of C. C and G could be both harmonics of the C an octave below (and the brain might even just assume it is), but the E could only be an harmonic of the C two octaves below.
Once you play chords you will find different effects affecting the sound, such as a beat between not only the notes, but also their overtones. Two sine waves in a 5th do sound quite pure (and even if you add a perfect 3rd it will sound quite pure). But if you look at their harmonics
you’ll find you get clashes between different combinations of the harmonics. This gets even more complex when you add the major third

C  -  c  - g - c' - e' - g' - bhf' - c''...
  E  -  e  -  b  -  e' -  g♯' - b'    - dhs'' ...
    G   -  g  - d'   -   g'  -  b'  -  d'' ...

(note that the b of the E is not the B of the G!) and even more if you have a minor third

C  -  c  - g - c' - e' - g' -  bhb' - c''...
  Eb  - eb - bb  - eb' - g' - bb'   - dhb'' ...
    G   -  g  - d'   -   g'  -   b'  -  d'' ...

This adds a lot vibrancy to the tone.
On top of this you have non linearity (the response of a combination is not the combination of the responses), which will actually create effects such as if you play a fifth the octave below the root sounding too (well observable at very high non linearity, such as heavy distortion).

root + octave + 12th + 15th + 18th + 20th not getting it. If the root is C0 then it is C0, C1, G1, C2, F2, A2? to me G1C2F2 does not sound pure

I'm also not familiar with the notation you've used for the chords and numbered nodes. Is that for guitar?

@SBF Sorry, that was not intended. This site has a weird implementation of a javascript fretboard formatting library that often leads to code blocks being interpreted as guitar chord notation. And the other one: Got offset by one for the top ones. Sorry, I’m not in too good condition currently, so I’m messing up a bit ... Of course this would be C0, C1, G1, C2, E2, G2, ...

ok, so harmonics of C0 then. What is bhf, dhs etc? Get well btw

What you wrote just scratches the surface. "the more consonant a sound is, the easier it will be for the brain to interpret notes as harmonics of the lower ones" - some counterexamples: 1. synthesize a sound by adding "consonant" sine waves. Depending on the amplitudes they will sound as a single note, or several. 2. harmonics of notes of stringed instruments are inharmonious and deviate from harmonic series, yet we normally don't hear them as separate notes, 3. percussive instruments often don't have harmonics at all, yet they sound as coherent notes.

@user1079505 I’ve never claimed that all consonant sounds sound as one (although could be seen as a definition of consonant that is truer to the word). Of course separation can also be achieved if the upper note is significantly stronger than what we’d expect for harmonics. But this is not what I have claimed. @1) Take a pair that sounds slightly like two notes. Change one note by a semitone. Suddenly it will sound a LOT like two notes. @2) The brain is used to inharmonicty. In fact the ear is not even able to discern the pitch at an exact frequency.

@user1079505 If the overtones were to deviate sufficiently you’d hear it, such as with bells. But as I said, the human brain knows inharmonicity, so it is able to interpret a slightly off overtone as harmonic. And the ear does not even give a clear pitch, but a pitch distribution, so the brain has a lot to work out there. @3) Pitched percussion does absolutely have overtones. Some of these have very inharmonic overtones, which we then call partial tones. These are then audible as distinct pitches.

@Tim Yes, that is stated with a sort of diagram in the answer.

Still wonder about bhb etc

@SBF halfflat/halfsharp. It is not exactly correct, but the natural 7ths (i.e. the 7th harmonic) is between a minor and a major seventh.

What’s a bhb then, b half flat? So it should be bhf?

@SBF But then bb should be bf. It is just notation.

it's not. I'm just not familiar with this notation perhaps

Loosely speaking, one doesn't hear overtones, because the fundamental is too loud in comparison.
There are exceptions, however. When singers, for example, produce a chord perfectly in tune, it's not unusual to hear overtones, as though there was one or more additional singers producing additional chord tones.
When playing an holding a tone on the trumpet, one can train oneself to hear overtones "within" that tone. (Interesting note about the trumpet: It doesn't actually produce the fundamental pitch. Playing middle C on a trumpet is actually a first overtone. For more on this: Trumpet Peculiar Frequency spectrum, What are brass instrument "pedal tones" and "false tones", and how are they different?, and related links.)
Another way to hear overtones as a chord in themselves is a little piano trick.

C4 is middle C.
Without producing any sound, depress and hold the keys for G4, C5, and E5.
Very loudly, strike and immediately release C3.
You will hear a C major chord formed by the G4, C5, and E5.


A cute piano trick! Wanna try, but I somehow doubt it will work on my Clavinova, a good imitation as it is in many ways :-)

@JyrkiLahtonen it probably works since the Yamaha P-80 I bought in 2000 already did it.

Is that piano trick related to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sympathetic_resonance ?

@Pam You got it. It’s the same reason the piano sounds louder or “bigger” when using the damper pedal.

Trumpet is a cylindrical instrument, not conical. Do you mean to say that it applies to both cylindrical and conical ones?

@user1079505 You’re right, of course. I’ve removed that part, since it’s addressed in the first linked post.

@ojs You were right! And I am surprised. Apparently I entertained some mistaken ideas about how sound is generated on my Clavinove :-)

That's an excellent question.  The basic answer is that the accompanying harmonics of a single tone are much weaker than the fundamental tones you play on the keys.  In addition, the fundamental tones of the keys are out of tune with the much weaker harmonics of the C, especially the E.

This is not true. For example low notes on piano have stronger harmonics than fundamental, and in the extreme end there is the missing fundamental effect where ears and brain fill in a fundamental frequency that is not there at all.

@ojs on the other hand one can often distinguish some of the individual harmonics in low piano notes. I think Scott is correct that this is a basic explanation, and a detailed one requires deeper study of human hearing.

@user1079505 I think this one of the explanations that sound plausible but don't match reality

"In addition, the fundamental tones of the keys are out of tune with the much weaker harmonics of the C, especially the E": but even if you tune the C, E, and G so the fundamentals aren't out of tune, you still hear a chord.

Slightly oversimplified answer
The perception issue comes down to sine waves, which are pure, "flavorless" pitches without overtones. Think of a very dull flute sound.  If you have a Hammond organ handy, push in all the drawbars but the one labeled "8".
If you play a chord of three sine waves at C3, G4, and E5 (C below middle C, G above middle C, and E above that G) it will sound like a single note with a woody, clarinet-like sound, instead of three flutes, because those three sine waves are behaving as a fundamental and two overtones.  The brain can hardly tell the difference.
But what if you play those same notes as a chord on a piano?  It will most likely sound like a chord, because each of those notes has overtones of its own, and the brain easily picks those notes out as separate.

Being an overtone is a transitive property, right? Then overtones of their own are overtones of the fundamental as well

Yes, but not ALL overtones are overtones of overtones. For instance, if a sound consists of overtones 4, 5, 8, 10, 12, 15,... and not the ones in between these, your ear will pick out the two independent harmonic series 4,8,12,... and 5,10,15,... and hear the two separate fundamental notes, a major third apart. But if you start adding 3, 7, etc., it will strengthen the missing fundamental.
